# construction of universal cover, loops

Tags: general-topology

In the following [document](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9605010), the author explains the construction of the universal cover on page 30 to 32. He considers paths between two arbitrary points on the manifold, x and y, and then suddenly switches to loops.

I quote: "Choose a base point x in M and consider the different paths from x to an other point y. Each path
belongs to a homotopy class γ of loops at x." He then assigns the new points in the UC as $ (y, \gamma) $ where y ranges over the points in the manifold and x is held fixed.

I know that homotopies are more general and that a circle is homotopic to a line (for instance) if they're considered as functions (in $\mathbb R^2$, for example). so in the above, should the quote not really have specified "of loops at x"? Because not everything in there will necessarily look like a loop?

Comment: I would assume "loops" is an error.  The usual construction takes all paths that emanate from the chosen point, but end wherever.  Then you identify as needed.

Comment: thank you v much sir